# What song plays just before the ending song of My Hero Academia episode 3?

Tags: music, my-hero-academia

Does anyone know the name of the song in *My Hero Academia* episode 3 that starts at 22:30 just before the ending song?

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be the full version of the ending theme "Heroes." Sounds like extra guitar improv from the ending theme itself